# Frontend is not communicating with backend in kubernetes

Tags: java, angular, nginx, kubernetes

I am currently developing some application that is divided to backend (java+spring) and frontend (angular). For now I wanted to put it to kubernetes but I have issues while communicating frontend with backend within kubernetes cluster.
I have frontend exposed as `LoadBalancer`, I am able to open it in the browser, however any API call to backend part is not resolving completely even without any status code - 400, 200, nothing.

I was trying to do it with nginx with reverse proxy, however no luck so far. Once I enter into the frontend pod and curl some healthcheck endpoint of my backend gateway - it's responding correctly so I assume there must be something wrong with nginx or frontend itself.

I've seen these questions already but couldn't make it work even with theirs ideas:

[connection refused from frontend to backend in k8s cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141863/connection-refused-from-frontend-to-backend-in-k8s-cluster)

[Angular on Kubernetes (ingress routing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989555/angular-on-kubernetes-ingress-routing)

Any ideas appreciated as I don't know for now what am I missing.

Here is my nginx config file:

```
upstream backend-service {
   server sm-gateway-service:8090;
}

server {
   listen   80;
   server_name  localhost;

   location / {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.html;
   }

   location /api {
       proxy_pass http://backend-service;
       proxy_buffer_size          128k;
       proxy_buffers              4 256k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
   }
}
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine3.14 as build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build-dev

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Use official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx:latest

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents.
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/client /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

`npm run build-dev` is just running the build with custom configuration for replacing environment url in Angular.
Environment url that is provided - `http://sm-gateway-service:8090/api` and it's base URL for all backend calls.

My frontend kubernetes yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  namespace: sm
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
    - host: sm-ui-frontend:6969
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: sm-gateway-service
                port:
                  number: 8090
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: sm-ui-frontend
                port:
                  number: 6969
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sm-ui-frontend
  name: sm-ui-frontend
  namespace: sm
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6969
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: sm-ui-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sm-ui-frontend
  name: sm-ui-frontend
  namespace: sm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sm-ui-frontend
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sm-ui-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sm-ui-frontend
          env:
            - name: ENVIRONMENT
              value: dev
          image: <image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources: {}
```

And finally my gateway service yaml that I would like to connect to from UI:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sm-gateway-service
  name: sm-gateway-service
  namespace: sm
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8090
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8090
  selector:
    app: sm-gateway-service
  type: ClusterIP

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sm-gateway-service
  name: sm-gateway-service
  namespace: sm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sm-gateway-service
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sm-gateway-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sm-gateway-service
          env:
            - name: JAVA_PARAMETERS
              value: -Xms200m -Xmx200m
          image: <image>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8090
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources: {}
```

Comment: First of all, please check your Ingress configuration. You are using the same host for frontend and backend, but previously mentioned that  URL should be `http://sm-gateway-service:8090/api` for backend. You can look at the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting), how to configure Ingress for different hosts

Comment: Are you sure using different hosts for frontend and backend?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin To be honest I am not sure, till now I had my application running in docker, frontend was exposed as sm-ui-frontend:6969 and gateway service as sm-gateway-service:8090 and wanted to work the same way on k8s.
About these hosts, does that mean when I hit gateway from frontend, I should have different ingress and host with /api path that send traffic to sm-gateway-service? I am not sure how it should work.